# I keep getting the error OperationalError at /forums/ no such table: forums_simple_post

Tags: python, django

I am building a simple forum application and I keep getting the error OperationalError at /forums/
no such table: forums_simple_post when I go on my forum page. Does anyone know how to fix this I would much appreciate the help?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from . import forms
from forums_simple.models import Post
# Create your views here.

class ForumForm(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'forums_simple/forum.html'
    form_class = forms.ForumForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_vaild(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_vaild(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'forums'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ForumForm.as_view(), name='forum')
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from  . import models

class ForumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ('message',)
```

forum.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  {% for message in object_list %}
    {{ post.message }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="container">
  <form class="forum_class" action="index.html" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    <button type="submit" name="big-button"></button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run migration commands?

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Also, I think that fixing this loop might help at some point:

```
# Bad
{% for message in object_list %}
  {{ post.message }}
{% endfor %}

# Good
{% for post in object_list %}
  {{ post.message }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried running the command but that did nothing and i tried fixing the loop but that also did nothing. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: Have you added  `'forums_simple'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?